# I have file problems

Tags: .net, file

I have problems to copy file from place. I am from Netherlands. Help now please.

```
var direktories = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\"  )

        FileInfo[] myFileOfStuffs =  direktories.GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo file1 in myFileOfStuffs)
        {
            file1.MoveTo(@"C:\Windows\System32");
        }
```

Files not copy.

Comment: Erm? Why are you trying to copy files from the framework to the system folder? Your problem is most likely a permission issue, and with GOOD REASON. Please tell me this is a Troll.

Comment: Are you sure the argument to `MoveTo` can be a directory? Maybe you need to combine the directory with the filename.

Comment: can you give us more explanation please? why are you trying to move files to certain destination?

Comment: paths no matter - are examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
file1.MoveTo(@"C:\Windows\System32\" + file1.Name);
```

This works for me but only once. You have to copy the files back.

Barmar is right too. If you have not the permission, please upgrade to Adminstrator

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of [FileInfo.MoveTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  you will notice that it takes file name as arguement. Whereas you are giving it a directory. So you should do it like this

```
file1.MoveTo( Path.Combine(@"C:\Windows\System32",file1.Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the permissions to move the files into the windows directory.